# Failing to implement an edit functionality in my application - dbUpdateEntityConcurrencyException ;

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building(for learning purposes) a web app with aps.net mvc and Entity framework.

In one of my controllers I have an edit method and a corresponding auto genereated view for it. Everything what i've done so far, seems fine, but for some reason when I try to actually edit something from my DB mu program stopps on the db.SaveChanges(); method in the Controller and I've no idea why.

The warning is :  dbUpdateEntityConcurrencyException was unhalted

Bellow I will post the code for my contorller and view :

```
private PostContext db = new PostContext();

     public ActionResult Edit(Post post)
        {
             if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(post);
            }
            db.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
```

And the view :

```
    @model class_project.Models.Post

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Post</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PostId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Can someone please help??

Comment: MVC webapps are `DbContext` disconnected scenarios: you use a new `DbContext` instance in each http request (I hope you do that, otherwise you have a design problem). So when you receive an existing entity through json code in the body of a request the controller deserializes it and creates an instance of your entity that is not attached to your `DbContext`. You have to attach it before setting the `entityState` and doing `SaveChanges`: something like `db.Posts.Attach(post)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have what you mentioned in your post, and not really sure how to do it. What I have is basically a dbcontext class created in my only model class. It's really simple, obviously. I just want to see how EF works in this way, nothing more. I tired your suggestion, but i still get the error.

Comment: A simple way to instantiate a `DbContext` for each request would be by wrapping all the method code inside a `using (var db = new PostContext()) { your code here }`. Do this in each controller method that handles an http request and uses your `DbContext`. So you create and dispose the `DbContext`. There are more advanced ways to do it, but this should work for your example app.

Comment: [This link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/d87001/connected-and-disconnected-scenario-in-entity-framework/) contains examples of disconnected `DbContext`and instantiating it with `using` instructions (the example app is not MVC, but the examples are relevant for your case). Take a look at the `UpdateEmployee` method.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `db.SaveChanges();`. You may find out it's hit twice.

Comment: is db disposed eventually? Also, what is the model for the class, what are the concurrencytokens and how are they configured?